# The tensorflow diagram model loads

Tags: tensorflow

Model loading failure
I downloaded the **vgg16_weights.npz** pretraining model, but it didn't load

```
    args = parser.parse_args()

    vgg_file = open(args.model_path, 'rb')

    vgg_model = vgg_file.read()
    vgg_file.close()

    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(vgg_model)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/weiyangbin/ChineseVQA/extract_fc7.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/weiyangbin/ChineseVQA/extract_fc7.py", line 39, in main
    graph_def.ParseFromString(vgg_model)
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

Comment: You are not specifying where are you getting this file from, so it is hard to tell what exactly you are supposed to do with it, but since the extension is `.npz`, it would seem it is a NumPy data file to load with [`np.load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html), not a TensorFlow graph definition. The file probably contains the weights of the model, but not the model definition itself. You should be able to get information about how to use this file from its provider (the source from where you got it in the first place).

Comment: Thanks, this model weight files comes from [vgg16_weights](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~frossard/post/vgg16/)